# d3.nest with variable children depth

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I have a tsv file with a simple "type" "count" content like this:

```
type    count
level1/level2/level3/Foo    24
level1/level2/level3/Bar    2
level1/level2/Baz   28
level1/level2/Quz   3
...
```

The `level` strings can be any String, i just named them like this here, to convey the meaning. The last element of the type, `Foo`, `Bar`, etc. can be considered to be the leafs of the data.

Using d3, i want to turn this into a sunburst diagram. To do so, i use the `d3.nest` function to break up the type at the slashes.

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.count = +d.count;
  });

  // define key functions for a depth up to 4 
  var nestedData = d3.nest()
     .key(function(d) { return level(d.type, 2); })
     .key(function(d) { return level(d.type, 3); })
     .key(function(d) { return level(d.type, 4); })
     .entries(data);

  // create the key for a specified level 
  function level(type, l) {
     var parts = type.split("/");
     var result = "";
     for (i = 0; i < l && i < parts.length; i++) {
        result += parts[i];
        if (i < l-1 && i < parts.length-1) {
            result += "/";
        }
     }
     return result;
  }
  ...
```

The issue here is that the resulting `nestedData` always has the entries/leafs at a depth of 4. In the example data you can see, that the leafs can be at any depth.

How can i construct nested data so that the entries can occur at any depth, not only at a predefined depth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `d3.nest` makes you register the nesting keys ahead of time before you call `nest.entries` there is no way to do a nesting with a variable number of levels by specifying everything up front.

One thing that might work is to recursively use a [nest.rollup](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-nest_rollup) function to control what the values at each level look like.  Inside your `rollup` you can decide if each entry element should be a new `d3.nest` containing the next level of detail, or if it should be a leaf node.

Here's a rough crack at it (assumes `level1` will always be present):

```
function rollupFn(group) {
    var leaves = [],
        groups = [];

    // Split the items into leaves and groups
    group.forEach(function(item) {
        // First eliminate level already accounted for by d3.nest key
        item.type = item.type.substr(item.type.indexOf('/')+1);

        if (item.type.indexOf('/') > -1) {
            groups.push(item);
        } else {
            leaves.push(item);
        }
    });

    // Convert the "group" items into a d3.nest object
    groups = d3.nest().key(function(d) {
            return d.type.split('/')[0];
        })
        .rollup(rollupFn)
        .entries(groups);

    var results = [];
    if (groups.length > 0) { results.push(groups); }
    if (leaves.length > 0) { results.push(leaves); }
    return results;
};

var nestedData = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return "level1" })  // optional: first group contains everything
    .rollup(rollupFn)
    .entries(data);
```

The values at each level will consist of one element containing a d3.nest object representing all lower levels followed by all of the leaf nodes.  If there are no further levels, the values array will be all leaf nodes.

Here is some working code you can step through: http://jsfiddle.net/S8aMU/10

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work. The documentation for `rollup` is sparse. Using this, the leaf nodes are all added to the second level of the nestedData. I think the issue may be that the `item.type` is reassigned, thus deleting levels in between.

Comment: I should have known the chances of me getting this right the first time was essentially zero. :P  I created a jsfiddle so I could play with it a bit so it should work better now.

Comment: This works great, thank you! For usage in a sunburst chart, i only changed it so that the `groups` and `leaves` elements are all directly in the `results` array.

Comment: That was quite helpful, thanks! I also changed the way it returns, instead of creating a `results` array and pushing groups and leaves, I just did `return groups.concat(leaves)`.